# scp not allowing file transfer except to home directory

Tags: ssh, file-transfer, scp, ssh-keys

I need to automate a file transfer using `scp` and I have created a new ssh key and sent the public key to the remote server where I'll be sending files to (@ ~/.ssh).

The problem is that it won't allow me to scp the file anywhere except the home directory. If I transfer it to the home directory, it works fine, but not anywhere else.

Is there something that needs to be done here? Thanks!

Comment: What command are you using to `scp` the file, and what error message do you get when you try?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show examples of scp commands that work and that don't work. Include the exact error message that you get when scp fails. It would also be helpful to include the permissions and ownership for the directories that you're failing to transfer into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can `scp` the file to your home directory, then your key is working. That is unlikely to be an issue.

The kinds of problems you might have would be:

#### You don't have permission to write to the destination directory

```
$ scp test.txt myserver:/root
scp /root/test.txt: Permission denied
```

In this case you need to get permission to write to the directory, or choose a different destination that you *do* have access to.

#### The destination directory doesn't exist

```
$ scp test.txt myserver:foo/bar/
scp foo/bar: No such file or directory
```

In this case, check that you're uploading to the correct path.

A destination like `myserver:foo/bar/` (note: no `/` after the `:`) means a relative path to your home directory. So, it might be `/home/seumasmac/foo/bar/` in this case.

A destination like `myserver:/var/www/` (note: there *is* a `/` after the `:`) is an absolute path. It means the directory `/var/www/` on the server.

The error that you get when you try to upload should tell you which of the above is the problem in this case.