# leverage sudo privileges with scp?

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo, scp

Built on top of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61245744/scp-not-allowing-file-transfer-except-to-home-directory).

When you try to scp to a machine, you use some user account, for example:

```
$ scp - private.key my_file.txt boris@my_server:~
```

Naturally, since you use a certain account, you only have write permissions to the home directory of that user.

My question is, if this user is a sudoer, and can perform sudo operations without requiring a password (the `ALL ALL ALL=ALL`  thingy :) , is it possible to leverage this to do the copy to a non-home directory (such as `etc/something`)  or do I have to first copy it to home directory, and then `ssh` to the machine and do the copying?

Comment: Not for `scp` specifically, but you can convince `rsync` to do this, setting `--rsync-path="sudo -n rsync"` for example

Answer (score 0):

Not with `scp`, but you can do it with `ssh`.

```
ssh boris@my_server sudo cp /dev/stdin my_file.txt < private.key
```

`/dev/stdin` reads from standard input, which is redirected to the `private.key` file.